# What are these rank represent in the Gate OP scene?

Tags: gate

So recently I just hook up this anime called *Gate* or *Jieitai Kanochi nite* and in the opening scene is very "fire" but I found that there's something kinda attracted me. It's the army rank. What are these rank called?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are ranks of the JSDF's Ground Self-Defense Force. These are the ranks of the member's of Itami's Third Recon Team, briefly shown in the first OP.

From [Wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_ranks_and_insignia_of_the_Japan_Self-Defense_Forces):

1. 陸士長 (Rikushichō) Leading Private [image]
2. 3等陸曹 (Santō rikusō) Sergeant [image]
3. 2等陸曹 (Nitō rikusō) Sergeant First Class [image]
4. (left to right) 陸曹長 (Rikusōchō) Sergeant Major and 1等陸曹 (Ittō rikusō) Master Sergeant [image] [image]
5. 2等陸尉 (Nitō rikui) First Lieutenant [image]

Comment: Wasn't expecting the rank was based on the real JSDF @@

Comment: @kit Apart from the isekai part of the story, everything else seems to be fairly accurate to their real-world counterparts. I liked the anime, too. Too bad there's no third season.